# Uploading files to Amazon S3 from a trigger

Tags: apex, callout, amazon-s3

I get files from an external webservice and have to upload them to Amazon S3 via apex. I found the unmanaged package [Force.com for Amazon Web Services a.k.a Amazon toolkit](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Amazon_Toolkit), but it looks rather outdated (SOAP instead of REST, incomplete code). I also don't want to use a paid app from the app exchange.

My use case is just uploading single files that I have in memory to S3. I don't want to create buckets, delete files etc. There is no visualforce involved.

Are there other code examples or packages available that I could use?

*More context if necessary*: In an external applciation, users can upload files. These files are passed on to Salesforce using a custom rest service. To store these files, we use the app S-Drive, which allows uploading and downloading files to Amazon S3 on managed Visualforce pages. To upload files using apex, you have to

1. Initialize the upload using the [S-Drive API](http://s-drive.s3.amazonaws.com/Docs/1.25/S-Drive%20User%20Guide%201.25.pdf).
2. Actually upload the file to S3 directly, using parameters you get from step 1.
3. Finalize the upload using the S-Drive API.

I need help with step 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the example code of [Jason Flammang](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsProfile?communityId=09aF00000004HMG&userId=005F0000003ug5c&showHeader=false) at https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BMDFIA4 (the posting from October 19, 2015, NOT the accepted answer.) I could adapt it to my purpose and it worked fine. I use it to do a http PUT to upload files to S3.

Changes I made to the example code:

- Instead of the local timezone, I use GMT.
- The filename has to be urlencoded, otherwise the signature will not be correct if it contains special characters (like ß), and the upload will be rejected (http 403).